# Ignore INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE when running application from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I know there is adb argument ("-d") to bypass the INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE error, to be exact:
adb install -r -d

but I wanted to know if there is a way to do the same thing without manually installing an app through adb but from within Android Studio. So when I Run/Debug application I'd like to ignore the error that is informing about downgrading an application, I want it to be overwritten by an older version of an app I'm running (keeping all the application data ofcourse - that's the point).

Is it possible?